# parseInt()/parseFloat() Funcion o método?

Tags: javascript

soy nuevo aquí.
Me gustaría hacer una pregunta (seguramente para la mayoria será una muy fácil de responder). agradezco de antemano las respuestas que puedan brindarme.

estoy aprendiendo JavaScript y me surgió una duda.
En JS las nombran Función parseInt() y ParseFloat(), según mi escaza comprensión, yo consideraba Función y Método como sinomimos, si esto es verdad, entonces:

1) Podríamos referirnos también como método parseInt() y método parseFloat()?

2) Entonces, a qué objeto pertenecen estos métodos (funciones)?

3) Si son métodos, entonces para usarlos, por qué no creamos una instancia del objeto?

4) Esto se debe a que serian métodos de un objeto que no necesita crear una instancia (creo que se conocen como objetos estáticos) es correcto mi idea?

Es todo y en verdad, les agradezco que me puedan dar un poco de luz, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

respondiendo a cada item por separado

1. Elemento de lista

   si...no trabaje mucho con javascript, pero si en java y ahi existen clases con métodos `parseInt`,`parseFloat`, etc. Deberas revisar la documentacion para saber msa al respecto
2. 3)  4)

estos metodos pertenecen a clases, no a objetos. Se llaman metodos de clase por queno necesitas instanciar la clase, es decir crear un objeto de la misma para poder usarlos. En java estos metodos se declaran con el modificador static. En java, la clase Integer proporciona un metodo "`static`" (que pertenece a la clase y no al objeto) al cual se puede llamar simplmente haciendo

```
int t=Integer.parseInt("3");
```

quien retorna la cadena "3" como un int
Esto es lo que se pero en java...me imagino que en javascript debe ser parecido. Si no...en el paradigma orientado a objetos, estos metodos si existen

Comment: hablas de java mientras la pregunta es JavaScript ?

Comment: el conocimiento se puede extrapolar

Comment: el sitio es para dar claridad a una respuesta no para hacer suposiciones bro, no lo tomes a mal, yo tambien pensaba lo mismo al comienzo hasta que los moredaradores me hicieron la correccion

Answer (score 1):

Convendría que no pienses a Javascript como otros lenguajes orientados a objetos tales como Java o C.

A `parseInt` y `parseFloat` puedes llamarle como quieras. Pero si quieres ceñirte a la realidad, ambos son definidos como *función*  en ECMA Script.

Por ejemplo, `parseInt` es definido así:

> La **función** `parseInt` produce un valor entero dictado por la
>   interpretación del contenido del argumento de cadena de acuerdo con la
>   raíz especificada. Se ignora el espacio blanco inicial en la cadena.
>   Si `radix` no está definido o es 0, se supone que es 10, excepto
>   cuando el número comienza con los pares de unidad de código 0x o 0X,
>   en cuyo caso se supone una raíz de 16. Si `radix` es 16, el número
>   también puede comenzar opcionalmente con los pares de unidad de código
>   0x o 0X.
>
> La función parseInt es el objeto intrínseco `% parseInt%`. Cuando se
>   llama a **la función `parseInt`**, se realizan los siguientes pasos:
>   ...
>
> [-`parseInt` en ECMA Script 18.2.5](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-parseint-string-radix)

---

Tu segunda pregunta... y la tercer... y la cuarta ... son respondidas leyendo el capítulo 18 de la especificación ECMA Script.

Allí se indica que `parseInt` y `parseFloat`... y otras, son funciones propias del llamado **Objeto global** (por eso te decía que no pienses a Javascript como a otros lenguajes).

> El objeto global:
>
> - se crea antes de que el control entre en cualquier contexto de ejecución.
> - no tiene un método interno [[Construct]]; no puede usarse como un constructor con el nuevo operador.
> - no tiene un método interno [[Call]]; no se puede invocar como una función.
> - tiene una ranura interna [[Prototype]] cuyo valor depende de la implementación.
> - puede tener propiedades definidas por el host además de las propiedades definidas en esta especificación. Esto puede incluir una
>     propiedad cuyo valor sea el objeto global en sí mismo.
>
> [- El Objeto Global en ECMA Script, apartado 18.](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-global-object)

Esto es esencial para entender el sentido de funciones como `parseInt` o `parseFloat` en Javascript, evitando equipararlas con métodos estáticos.

Más adelante, [el apartado 18.2 enumera las funciones propias del Objeto Global](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-function-properties-of-the-global-object), entre las cuales se encuentran [`parseFloat` (apartado 18.2.4)](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-parsefloat-string) y [`parseInt` (apartado 18.2.5)](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-parseint-string-radix).

Creo que con esto respondemos a tu ¿cuestinario?  :-)